# How to deal with questions which appear to be bugs?

Tags: discussion, questions

In the really early state of Ethereum, some questions may turn out to be bugs or based on issues caused by bugs. [Like this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/900/87).

How to deal with questions which appear to be bug reports? Close? Answer with link to bug tracker?

Comment: Interesting question - obviously when I made the post I was not sure that it was in fact a bug.

I think it is still useful to allow possible bug questions because StackExchange gives more visibility to our potential developer community.

I'd say once confirmed, link to bug tracker and close seems reasonable.

Comment: Could you answer instead of comment? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

Obviously when I made the post in question I was not sure that it was in fact a bug.

I think it is still useful to allow possible bug questions because StackExchange gives more visibility to our potential developer community.

I would say that once confirmed, a link to the bug tracker should be added, and the question closed.

I don't know if it is possible to also then add a tag such as 'confirmed-bug' so that anyone who stumbles upon the question is made aware..

Answer (score 2):

I think we should allow most such questions.

It is usually not clear if it is indeed a bug.

Now if it's written as a bug report, which oftentimes don't even pose a question but just a list of assertions, then I think we can answer with a link to the appropriate bug tracker.  Obviously, if a particular user keeps doing this, using SE for bug reports instead of Github, then we could start closing their questions.

Comment: +1 I fully agree with that.